# Alignment of flex items

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper which is `display:flex` and equally spaces the items horizontally. Those items have `display:flex` also but are `flex-direction:column` these are basically an image and a span wrapped in a button. What is happening is when the span the breaks onto 2 lines it misaligning the top of the images so they look out of line, is there a way around this?

[You can see the problem here](https://codepen.io/87Development/pen/mdqwmvB)

Comment: Please add a [mre]!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've got `align-items: center` on your main `.bottle-refill-options` container, which is vertically centering everything.

Change this to `align-items: flex-start;` and all your items will vertically center along the top, giving the look (i think) you want

Comment: Thats embarrasing how did I not see that!